# The main element must not appear as a descendant of the section element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix the errors of my site that appear in the W3C Markup Validator:
https://validator.w3.org/nu

One of the errors that I can't fix is:

> The main element must not appear as a descendant of the section
>   element

The code in this area is:

```html
<section id="sp-section-2">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="sp-title" class="col-lg-12 ">
   <div class="sp-column "/>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<section id="sp-main-body">
 <div class="row">
  <main id="sp-component" class="col-lg-12 " role="main">
   <div class="sp-column ">
    <div id="system-message-container">
    </div>
```

Tried to move or change the name but can't make it work.

Comment: What is unclear …? `main` should not occur inside a `section`, because `main` is the “bigger”, more important grouping element … so `<section id="sp-main-body"><div class="row"><main id="sp-component" […]` is what you need to fix.

Comment: I understand that, but it's how the premium template I'm using is set up. And whatever I try to fix it, breaks the template.

Comment: What part did you change if at all?

Comment: What kind of premium template are we talking about? You did not mention which templating system you're using.

Comment: I'm using a template with the Helix framework. I tried to move the main id out of the section using the ReReplacer plugin but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<main>` element can't be child of `<section>` this is what the rules of w3c you cannot escape it you have to follow the structure.

As you have already written the code so I suggest you to replace the section element with `div` element so you can be error free  but this not the valid standards of w3c but only for error free.

Comment: Used a dirty hack changing on the fly the tag from section to div using the ReReplacer plugin (Joomla), and now the error seems to be gone.
Thanks Mohammed.

Answer (score 0):

`<main>` can't be a descendant of `<section>`. That is what the message says and that is, what your code has

```
<section id="sp-section-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="sp-title" class="col-lg-12 ">
      <div class="sp-column "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="sp-main-body">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- here is the <main> that causes the warning -->
    <main id="sp-component" class="col-lg-12 " role="main">
      <div class="sp-column ">
        <div id="system-message-container">
<!--- ... -->
```